# Getting each record two times - PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form where you can select your choice as per your need, after selection when you hit submit button you will be redirected to search listing page where you can check user's listings, everything is working fine but the problem is i am getting each record two times.

From the following code:

```
<?php

include_once('dbconn.php');

$looking_for = $_POST['looking_for'];
$religion = $_POST['religion'];
$mother_tongue = $_POST['mother_tongue'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN profile_description where gender like '".$looking_for."' AND religion like '%".$religion."%' AND mother_tongue like '%".$mother_tongue."%'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_row(($result))){

$profile_created_by = $result_row[1];
$religion = $result_row[6];
$mother_tongue = $result_row[7];
$city = $result_row[15];
$community = $result_row[16];
$height = $result_row[17];
$education_level = $result_row[23];
$education_field = $result_row[24];
$working_with = $result_row[26];
$describe_yourself = $result_row[28];

?>
<div class="search_list wrap">
<p>Profile created by <?php echo ucwords($profile_created_by); ?></p>
<div class="search_list_image">
<img src="img/groom-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="profile_basic">

<label class="label">Age / Height</label><div class="info">25, <?php echo $height; ?></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="spacer_4"></div>

<label class="label">Religion</label><div class="info"><?php echo ucwords($religion); ?></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="spacer_4"></div>

<label class="label">Mother Tongue</label><div class="info"><?php echo ucwords($mother_tongue); ?></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="spacer_4"></div>

<label class="label">Community</label><div class="info"><?php echo ucwords($community); ?></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="spacer_4"></div>

<label class="label">Location</label><div class="info"><?php echo ucwords($city); ?></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="spacer_4"></div>

<label class="label">Education</label><div class="info"><?php echo ucwords($education_level); ?> - <?php echo ucwords($education_field); ?></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="spacer_4"></div>

<label class="label">Profession</label><div class="info"><?php echo ucwords($working_with); ?></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="search_list_link">
<a href="#">View full profile</a>
</div>
<div class="search_list_content">
<p><?php echo $describe_yourself; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried a Group By at the end of your query?

Comment: @SariRahal Yes but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to the Join by which column you want to join the two tables. Or else each column from the user table will be duplicated when you have more than one profile_description for a user

Comment: And don't use the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated since php 5.5. Use the PDO or mysqli_* functions instead

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Table_ID),info, ... FROM user INNER JOIN profile_description where gender like '".$looking_for."' AND religion like '%".$religion."%' AND mother_tongue like '%".$mother_tongue."%'";
```

This wouldn't work is if you had multiple entries with the same ID.  In that case, it will just grab the first entry.